# rebuild tables without dropping content Symfony

Tags: symfony1

I was wondering...Is it possible to rebuild the database on Symfony without dropping the current content ?
If it is, how ?

I'd like to be able to modify one table without dropping all the current content of all my tables

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually modify the table (either command line, or a database GUI), and then regenerate the schema and model files without losing any data. Is there something that would prevent you from doing it this way? PHPmyadmin, navicat or other GUI's make this very easy and efficient to make changes on a live application.

```
symfony doctrine:build-schema
symfony doctrine:build-model
symfony cc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so you are saying that, if I have a lot of content in my db, and if I change my schema, do the three command line you just wrote, I still keep my data ?

Comment: Yes. You could build and manage the entire database independently and then build it into a Doctrine ORM. If you have large complicated databases that you anticipate to make a lot of schema changes on, it may be much easier to do it this way.

Comment: It's me again ! Ok, so  I did what you told me too, but now, the problem is that everything is messed up probably because of the DoctrineGuardPlugin. The build-schema generated all the sfGuardUser tables but with Symfony, the sfGuardUSer tables are in a separate schema...

Answer (score 1):

yes you can if you use Doctrine for example, with the doctrine migration tool.

The documentation isn't that good so here is some must-read:

- http://particul.es/blog/index.php?post/Doctrine-generate-migrations-or-how-to-upgrade-your-database-in-production
- http://www.slideshare.net/weaverryan/the-art-of-doctrine-migrations

If you don't have Doctrine, you can still use an external tool like liquid base but it's much more diffucult to setup.

Comment: Thanks ! But the problem is that I have a huge database, so i don't want to empty my content in a yml file to then put it back again in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok!

So it turned out that all I had to do was update my schema.yml file, update my database "by hand" directly on myphpadmin, and then run a "php symfony build --all-classes" to update all my models, forms and filters according to the new schema !

Thanks everyone for pushing me to go through all the documentation and be able to answer my question !